# Deleting row from table in Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle

in Database I have table №1 which is referenced by foreign keys in many other tables. Constraints on those other tables restrict deleting from table №1, so I can not just delete row from table №1 without risk of getting Oracle error.

Can I check is some row from table №1 is actually referenced right now by any other table? That is important for me because while deleting the row I won't be able to handle possible exceptions, and I need to be sure that deleting goes well.

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something.  Wouldn't you just check each of the child tables to see whether a row exists with the particular value?  Assuming these tables are not static, though, this seems rather fraught since a row could be inserted into one of the child tables between the time that you do the check and the time that you try to do the delete.  Even if you wrote the check, you'd still want to have the `delete` process handle errors sensibly.

Comment: @Justin Cave Checking each of the child tables seems almost impossible because there is a lot them, and what is worse in future other child table may appear, so I would need to always maintain list of child tables to check.

Comment: OK.  So then potentially your question could be updated to how to dynamically do that check.  You could use `dba_`, `all_`, or `user_constraints` to find all the foreign key constraints that reference the parent table and then use dynamic SQL to construct all the SQL statements to check whether a child row exists.  That's a decent amount of code (depending on the assumptions that can be made) but doable.  It's a lot more complicated than a static SQL solution that just lists the child tables but if you have hundreds of child tables, it may be worth it.

Comment: you can also use cascade delete on your FKs to automatically delete a child record when the parent record is deleted.

Comment: @Justin Cave  Honestly, I was hoping that there is exist some unknown to me key word in Oracle SQL, like "can_delete", or some voodoo-black-old magic query construction to perform my task...

Comment: Depends what you want to happen.  The code that does the actual delete could `log errors into` a log table so that any rows that failed to delete would be ignored (until someone came back and examined the error table to see why the row failed to delete) but that generally falls under the "handle errors sensibly" framework.  You could modify all your foreign key constraints (and all the foreign key constraints that reference those tables, recursively) to do a cascade delete if you want the decendent rows to be deleted automatically when you delete the parent.

Comment: @Ultra_Igor - there is no magic construct.

Comment: If you want to perform some preliminary check then you should have *something* that would handle its result. So you may handle delete errors in the same *something*, because Oracle will perform all the checks  for you (that may be quite complex if dependent tables have or will have `on delete` triggers, for example). What is the issue with replacement of `delete` with `begin delete... exceptions when ... end` or exception handling at the host language itself?